# Cannot loop items from a string array using PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell, for-loop

I have the following code and I cannot loop the items using PowerShell.

```
$ipAddress = @('107.20.253.26', '107.20.178.220', '8.8.8.8')

for($i=0; $i -le $ipAddress.count; $i++) {

    $resolve = nslookup $i | Format-list
    $resolve | Out-File $resolveFile

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, this loops over the IPs fine. There is an easier way to do in PowerShell though using `foreach`.
And remove `Format-Table`; it is useful when writing to host but just turned your `nslookup` result to `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData` datatype.
Use `-Append` with `Out-File` to avoid overwriting previous result.

```
$ipAddress = @('107.20.253.26', '107.20.178.220', '8.8.8.8')

foreach($ip in $ipAddress) {

    # remove Format-Table
    $resolve = nslookup $ip

    # Add Append flag so that you are not overwriting previous contents on each loop
    $resolve | Out-File $resolveFile -Append

}
```

Comment: Great solution. Thank you very much. This worked really great and effortlessly.